# How to create a matrix based on another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that is 30 rows and 12 columns.  I want to create another matrix that is based off this original matrix.  I want to make the entries in the first 6 columns to be 2 times the entries of the original matrix.  I want to make the entries in the 7-11 columns to be 1.5 times the entires of the original matrix.  I want the 12th column to be the same as the original matrix.

I have the following code, but it does not give me the output that I am looking for

```
sales=matrix(rpois(360, 10), nrow=30)
sales_dol=matrix(, nrow=30, ncol=12)

for (j in 1:12) {
  if (j<7)
    sales_dol[,j]=sales[,j]*2
} else if (j<12){
    sales_dol[,j]=sales[,j]*1.5
} else{
    sales_dol[,j]=sales[,j]
} 

 sales_dol
```

Comment: Conceptually the code you've written works, there's just a  problem with matching braces, the for loop brace ends just before the `j<12` line. To fix, add a `{` after `(j<7)` and another `}` after the `}`

Answer (score 2):

Since R functions are vectorised you don't need a `for` loop to do this.

```
set.seed(123)
sales=matrix(rpois(360, 10), nrow=30)
head(sales)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    8   12   11    6   10   16    9    6   10    14     8    12
#[2,]    9   11   12   15    8    7   10    9   11    12     7     7
#[3,]   14    9    9   10   10   15   10   16   10    16     8    11
#[4,]   10    9    9   13   17    6   13    9    4    13    10    16
#[5,]   10    8    7    8   16   11    8    5    7    11     7     9
#[6,]   15    7    7    7    5    8    6    4    9     7    10     3

sales_dol <- cbind(sales[, 1:6] * 2, sales[, 7:11] * 1.5, sales[, 12])
head(sales_dol)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]   16   24   22   12   20   32 13.5  9.0 15.0  21.0  12.0    12
#[2,]   18   22   24   30   16   14 15.0 13.5 16.5  18.0  10.5     7
#[3,]   28   18   18   20   20   30 15.0 24.0 15.0  24.0  12.0    11
#[4,]   20   18   18   26   34   12 19.5 13.5  6.0  19.5  15.0    16
#[5,]   20   16   14   16   32   22 12.0  7.5 10.5  16.5  10.5     9
#[6,]   30   14   14   14   10   16  9.0  6.0 13.5  10.5  15.0     3
```